# https not working with Javascript Fetch API

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript

i've been using http with fetch API for my nativescript App and its been working, my url was `http://saved-proficiencies.000webhostapp.com/`

Now I have to change the url to this `https://www.mirrackle.com/`

The issue i have is, whenever I use `https://www.mirrackle.com/`, it gives this error -

> Network request failed.

When I use `http://www.mirrackle.com`, it says page has been moved permanently to `https://www.mirrackle.com/`

this is my code

```js
var url = "https://www.mirrackle.com/backend/login.php?email=" + 
    encodeURIComponent(this.get("email")) + "&password=" + 
    encodeURIComponent(this.get("password"));
fetch(url).then((response) => response.text()).then((res) => {
  alert(res);
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: I would not be happy sending userid and password unencrypted over a GET

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognize the encode URIComponent pattern.
if json doesn't work, new FormData(); is probably a better choice anyway.

```
const url = "https://www.mirrackle.com/backend/login.php";
const data = {email:this.get("email"), password:this.get("password")};
const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
const options = {
    method:"POST",
    body: jsonData
}
fetch(url,options)
    .then(response=> response.json())
    .then(response=> alert(response))
    .catch(e=>console.log(e));
```

Comment: hello, i've tried this, thanks. I still get the "Network Request Failed" error...Could it be related to my hosting company? cause my other apps don't do this - i used a different hosting company for them

Comment: Access to fetch at 'https://www.mirrackle.com/backend/login.php' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.


this is a response error that I am getting. if i dig deep in. it's a cross origins issue it looks like. not something I have dealt with yet.

Comment: thanks, i have added header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); still doesn't work...my previous hosting company never gave me this issue, maybe i'll go back to them

Comment: so if you are accessing your back-end from your own front- and not another front end, make sure it doesn't work in the live environment if you have a different testing environment? reading up on failed fetches... (last i remember there were ways for that error to come up before the 'fetch' has even left).